# CiviCase notes available only to self and manager, not other workers?

Tags: wordpress, civicase, acl

Am I able to have case workers that can create a confidential note in a case, and these notes would not be available to any other workers (only the manager).

And also it needs to prevent with View/Edit Contact access from seeing this information as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/activitytypeacl but I don't remember exactly how it works with cases.

Or there's no UI for it currently but the same notes that can be attached to contacts/contributions can theoretically be attached to cases or activities, and then you could use [hook_civicrm_notePrivacy](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_notePrivacy/).